# Integration of wkhtmltopdf for a link is not working

Tags: php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to convert html source to pdf. But unfortunately, its not working fine. 
https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp
I have gone through this link and this integration is not working for this link
http://raindrops.in/ainvvy/view/527a727a4251df44558b4567
What is the problem with it? Please let me know

Comment: Your best bet is to get it working via command line. If that works, hit it via PHP with `shell_exec` instead of a PHP wrapper.

Comment: What does "not working" mean for you? Does it return an error code? StackOverflow? Do you get errors or anything in stderr? Do you get a broken PDF?